# Unable to make leaflet map responsive - tried using flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, leaflet

So I have this web page which contains a leaflet map and a form, when a user enters their address
it says how far from the location they are
I was able to make the form responsive with flexbox 
unfortunately this isn't the case for the leaflet map
I am still fairly new to css and javascript


I looked around on stackoverflow to find a solution and came across a link where I can make the map responsive but that only worked when the map took up the whole width of box it was placed in 
However in my case, I did not want the map to span across the whole screen

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Heres my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>INDEX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>

    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin="">
  </script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">





</head>
<body>



<div class="location-form-Wrapper">
    <form action="#" method="post" class ="space">
    <div class="location-form-row">
        <fieldset class="field_set1">
            <legend class="legend1">Search Address</legend>
            <div class="location-form-space">
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="address" id="addr">
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" class="location-form-btn"onclick="addySearch();">
                    <br /> <br />
                    <label class="latitude-space">Latitude </label>
                    <input type = "text" placeholder="Latitude" id="lat">

                    <br/> <br/>
                    <label class="longitude-space">Longitude </label>

                    <input type = "text" placeholder="Longitude" id="lon">
                    <br /> <br />
                    <div id="distance" class="distance">  </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>


        <div id="distance" class="distance">  </div>
     </div>


    </form>


</div>



<div class="map-row">



    <div class="map-col">

      <div id="mapid"></div>
     </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My CSS

```
.location-form-Wrapper{
display:flex;
 margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;



justify-content: space-around;
 align-items:center;

}

.location-form-row{

display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;


}

.location-form-space{
    padding:30px;
}

.location-form-btn{
    margin-left:18px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:2px;
    padding-right:2px;

}



.longitude-space{
    padding-right:3px;
}

.latitude-space{
    padding-right:15px;
}


#mapid{
margin-top:20px;




height: 500px;
width: 1000px;



 }

 .location-map-wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;

 }


.container{


}

.map-row{
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:space-around;

}

.map-col{
    min-wdith:300px;
    height:500px;

}
```

And My JS

```
<script>


var ConcordiaLat = 45.495675;
var ConcordiaLong = -73.578667;
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([ConcordiaLat,ConcordiaLong],14);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' + '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' + 'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
}).addTo(mymap);


<!-- var circle1 = L.circle([ConcordiaLat, ConcordiaLong], { -->
    <!-- color: 'green', -->
    <!-- fillColor: '#008000', -->
    <!-- fillOpacity: 0.5, -->
    <!-- radius: 1000 -->
<!-- }).addTo(mymap); -->



var marker = L.marker([ConcordiaLat, ConcordiaLong], {

}).addTo(mymap);


marker.bindPopup("Located at 1455 Boulevard de Maisonneuve O, Montréal, QC H3G 1M8").openPopup();

var x , y;


function addySearch()
{

     //Creating the marker to a searched address
            //A sample address. You must get it from the input box
            var addr = document.getElementById("addr");


             <!-- var addr = document.getElementById("add").value -->
                var lat = document.getElementById("lat");
                var lon = document.getElementById("lon");



            //AJAX CODE to get Lat Long from the address
            //NO MODIFICATION REQUIRED
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&limit=3&q=" + addr.value;
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                //myArr is an array of the matching addresses
                //You can extract the lat long attributes
                //Example: myArr[0].lat and myArr[0].lon;
                lat.value = myArr[0].lat;
                lon.value = myArr[0].lon;



                //Create markers from the info. Check library reference
               // var latlng = L.LatLng(ConcordiaLat, ConcordiaLong);
               // L.circleMarker(latlng, { color: "red", radius: 1000 });

                //Use Polyline to draw line on map
                //https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html

                //Compute Distance using
                //(from.distanceTo(to)).toFixed(0)/1000;
                //from and to are latlong objects from the circleMarkers above


                x = lat;
                y = lon;




var marker2 = L.marker([x.value, y.value], {

}).addTo(mymap);




var latlngs = [
    [x.value , y.value],
    [45.495675 , -73.578667]

];

    var markerFrom = L.circle([x.value, y.value] );
    var markerTo =  L.circle([45.495675, -73.578667] );

    var from = markerFrom.getLatLng();
    var to = markerTo.getLatLng();



    document.getElementById('distance').innerHTML = ("Your distance from our store is " + (from.distanceTo(to)).toFixed(0)/1000) + 'km';


var polyline = L.polyline(latlngs, {color: 'red'}).addTo(mymap);

// zoom the map to the polyline
map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

            }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();

}







</script>
```